# Codeigniter error: Undefined offset: 1 when processing checkbox from form

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, undefined, offset

I get this error type of error everytime I submit a form and process it.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 1

Filename: controllers/register_grp.php

Line Number: 81
```

I have this form which contains dynamically created checkboxes, the number of which is determined by the user.

```
<input class='main' type='checkbox' name='tshirttick[1]' id='tshirttick1' value='Yes' />
<input class='main' type='checkbox' name='tshirttick[2]' id='tshirttick2' value='Yes' />
...
```

Upon submit, I process it with this code:

```
$withtshirt = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('tshirttick'));
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_of_members; $i++)
{
     if ($withtshirt[$i] == "Yes")
     {
          $include_shirt = 'Y';
          $ticketcost += 150;
          $tshirtsize[$i] = $this->db->escape($tshirtsize[$i]);
     }
     else
     {
          $include_shirt = 'N';
          $tshirtsize[$i] = "-";
          $tshirtsize[$i] = $this->db->escape($tshirtsize[$i]);
     }
     $id = $this->register_model->addParticipant($i, $tshirtsize[$i], $include_shirt);
}
```

The model **addParticipant** basically inserts a row into the database returns **$this->db->insert_id();**

The line number 81 pointed to by the error is this line:

```
if ($withtshirt[$i] == "Yes")
```

The rows are actually inserted successfully, but multiple instances of this error prints upon submitting, preventing the page from redirecting to another page. I guess the error prints everytime the loop iterates.

How will I fix this? I just want the page to redirect after it executes all the insertion, but this 'notice' prevents it.

Comment: is it undefined offset 1 every time or does the number increment?

Comment: the number increments. the error prints multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Your checkbox names should be like `tshirttick[]`

```
<input class='main' type='checkbox' name='tshirttick[]' id='tshirttick1' value='Yes' />
<input class='main' type='checkbox' name='tshirttick[]' id='tshirttick2' value='Yes' />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried that. The problem with not putting index in the checkbox array is when some boxes are checked and some are not, only the checked ones are being received.

for example:
tshirttick1 = checked
tshirttick2 = not checked
tshirttick3 = checked
tshirttick4 = not checked

the array will look like
tshirttick[1] = 'Yes'
tshirttick[2] = 'Yes'
tshirttick[3] = ''
tshirttick[4] = ''

Answer (score 0):

The inputs are creating an array with a string for the key. PHP can't find the value associated with the string key and realizes it can convert the string to a number so it converts the string to a number and throws a notice.

you can set the field names without keys and they will automatically populate the array. `name='tshirttick[]'`. You can also [type cast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) `$i` to a string in your foreach loop. `$i = (string) $i;`